# jquery dynamic input disabling and refresh on change

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am working with input elements that need to switch back and forth between being disabled and enabled. When the user selects a year from the dropdown menu, that particular year should be disabled in the input element. However, when the user changes a year, the new year should be disabled.

Here's the jQuery that I have come up with. It works fine except for it does not refresh when a new change is made. i.e. multiple years can be disabled which is not appropriate for the app. Only one year can disabled at any given time.

```
$.getJSON('/ResidentialBuilding/getYear', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("#standards").append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + value.year + '"' + 'id="' + value.year + '">' + value.year + '</input><br>');
    });
});
$("#ResidentialStandardYear").change(function () {
    standardValue = $("#ResidentialStandardYear").val();
    console.log(standardValue);
    disabled = "";
    if (standardValue == $("#" + standardValue).attr('id')) {
        console.log($('#' + standardValue));
        disabled = "disabled";
        $('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', disabled);
    }
});
```

Here's a screenshot for a visual reference:

[image]

Comment: which input element you want to diable?

Comment: If 2003 is selected, 2003 should be disabled. The issue right now is on the second run of the on change event, 2003 and 2006 are both disabled. Only one input element can be disabled at any given time

Comment: i mean you are trying to disable dropdown items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to clear all other `"disabled"` attributes when you enable one on the new checkbox. Something that should go along the lines:

```
$("#ResidentialStandardYear").change(function () {
    standardValue = $("#ResidentialStandardYear").val();
    console.log(standardValue);
    disabled = "";
    if (standardValue == $("#" + standardValue).attr('id')) {
        console.log($('#' + standardValue));
        disabled = "disabled";
        $('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', disabled);
        $('input[type=checkbox]').not('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Also, keep in mind the call to `.attr('disabled', disabled)` is expecting a boolean, not a string. Calling `.attr('disabled', '')` and `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` will both disable an input.

Comment: Thank you. Had never heard of the .not method

Comment: There's some excellent documentation on it here: http://api.jquery.com/:not/ ; there's also a `:not` selector that does pretty much the same thing: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/